# Javascript Loop <UL> rotate a list with one click

Tags: javascript

I have the following function below that is supposed to rotate/loop through a list of 4 items, which does work through an onclick. However, the user has to click twice for the loop to perform.

```
function rotateList(){
var list = document.getElementById("arrange");
var first = list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
list.appendChild(first);
}
```

Does anyone know how to make the above work with one click?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function rotateList() {
    var list = document.getElementById("arrange");
    list.appendChild(list.firstElementChild);
}
```

Note that any DOM node can only ever exist once in the document. If you append it in one place, it gets removed in its original location.

This way appending the first child node has the desired effect.

`firstElementChild` gives you the "real" first child, whereas `firstChild` also gives you the (blank) text node that can occur between elements, which is what's making you click twice. However, `firstElementChild` is not supported before IE9. [Other browsers are no problem.](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t82)

http://jsfiddle.net/Vb8dY/1/

Comment: You are right, they have to use `firstElementChild`. I'm currently researching how widely that's supported.

Comment: This.. is bloody clean.

Comment: Many thanks, this was driving me nuts! Thank you for the demo @wared

Comment: Always double check your expectations. The same thing got me in the first version of my answer - but I immediately checked whether `firstChild` actually does what I expect.